# Magento 2.3 Installation error at 66%

Tags: magento2, module, magento2.3, installation

Magento 2 Installation error at 66%

Hi everybody !

I am having an issue installing Magento 2.

I followed every step and everything went fine until installation.

The installation stops at 66% stating that it is incomplete.

I tried to find a solution for this issue online but so far, I didn't.

Some help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Here is the console log :

```
Starting Magento installation:
File permissions check...

Required extensions check...

Enabling Maintenance Mode...

Installing deployment configuration...

Installing database schema:
Schema creation/updates:
Module 'Aheadworks_Freeshippinglabel':

Module 'Magento_Store':

Module 'Magento_Directory':

Module 'Magento_Backend':

Module 'Magento_Theme':

Module 'Magento_AdminNotification':

Module 'WeltPixel_ThankYouPage':

Module 'WeltPixel_TitleRewrite':


Installing user configuration...

Enabling caches:
Current status:
Array
(
[config] => 1
[layout] => 1
[block_html] => 1
[collections] => 1
[reflection] => 1
[db_ddl] => 1
[compiled_config] => 1
[eav] => 1
[customer_notification] => 1
[config_integration] => 1
[config_integration_api] => 1
[full_page] => 1
[target_rule] => 1
[amasty_shopby] => 1
[config_webservice] => 1
[translate] => 1
[vertex] => 1
[wp_gtm_categories] => 1
)


Installing data...
Data install/update:
Module 'Aheadworks_Freeshippinglabel':
Installing data...
[ERROR] Exception: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/html/stacked-skincare.local/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Config.php on line 341 in /var/www/html/stacked-skincare.local/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/stacked-skincare.local/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Config.php(341): Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, 'Invalid argumen...', '/var/www/html/s...', 341, Array)
#1 /var/www/html/stacked-skincare.local/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Config.php(388): Magento\Eav\Model\Config->_initEntityTypes()
#2 /var/www/html/stacked-skincare.local/generated/code/Magento/Eav/Model/Config/Interceptor.php(63): Magento\Eav\Model\Config->getEntityType('customer')
#3 /var/www/html/stacked-skincare.local/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/AbstractEntity.php(307): Magento\Eav\Model\Config\Interceptor->getEntityType('customer')
#4 /var/www/html/stacked-skincare.local/generated/code/Magento/Customer/Model/ResourceModel/Customer/Interceptor.php(180): Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\AbstractEntity->setType('customer')
#5 /var/www/html/stacked-skincare.local/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/ResourceModel/Customer.php(75): Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\Interceptor->setType('customer')
#6 /var/www/html/stacked-skincare.local/generated/code/Magento/Customer/Model/ResourceModel/Customer/Interceptor.php(14): Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer->__construct(Object(Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\VersionControl\Snapshot), Object(Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\VersionControl\RelationComposite), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Config\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Framework\Validator\Factory), Object(Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime), Object(Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager), Array)
#7 /var/www/html/stacked-skincare.local/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(116): Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\Interceptor->__construct(Object(Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\VersionControl\Snapshot), Object(Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\VersionControl\RelationComposite), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Config\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Framework\Validator\Factory), Object(Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime), Object(Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager), Array)
#8 /var/www/html/stacked-skincare.local/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(66): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Custome...', Array)
#9 /var/www/html/stacked-skincare.local/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Custome...')
#10 /var/www/html/stacked-skincare.local/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(160): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Custome...')
#11 /var/www/html/stacked-skincare.local/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(246): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\Custome...', NULL, 'customerResourc...', 'Magento\\Custome...')
#12 /var/www/html/stacked-skincare.local/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('Magento\\Custome...', Array, Array)
#13 /var/www/html/stacked-skincare.local/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\Custome...', Array, Array)
#14 /var/www/html/stacked-skincare.local/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Custome...')
#15 /var/www/html/stacked-skincare.local/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(160): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Custome...')
#16 /var/www/html/stacked-skincare.local/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(246): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\Custome...', NULL, 'customerReposit...', 'Magento\\Checkou...')
#17 /var/www/html/stacked-skincare.local/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('Magento\\Checkou...', Array, Array)
#18 /var/www/html/stacked-skincare.local/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\Checkou...', Array, Array)
#19 /var/www/html/stacked-skincare.local/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Checkou...')
#20 /var/www/html/stacked-skincare.local/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(160): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Checkou...')
#21 /var/www/html/stacked-skincare.local/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(246): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\Checkou...', NULL, 'checkoutSession', 'Aheadworks\\Free...')
#22 /var/www/html/stacked-skincare.local/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('Aheadworks\\Free...', Array, Array)
#23 /var/www/html/stacked-skincare.local/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Aheadworks\\Free...', Array, Array)
#24 /var/www/html/stacked-skincare.local/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(56): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Aheadworks\\Free...', Array)
#25 /var/www/html/stacked-skincare.local/generated/code/Aheadworks/Freeshippinglabel/Api/Data/LabelInterfaceFactory.php(43): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('\\Aheadworks\\Fre...', Array)
#26 /var/www/html/stacked-skincare.local/vendor/aheadworks/module-freeshippinglabel/Setup/InstallData.php(123): Aheadworks\Freeshippinglabel\Api\Data\LabelInterfaceFactory->create()
#27 [internal function]: Aheadworks\Freeshippinglabel\Setup\InstallData->process()
#28 /var/www/html/stacked-skincare.local/vendor/magento/framework/App/State.php(187): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#29 /var/www/html/stacked-skincare.local/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/State/Interceptor.php(89): Magento\Framework\App\State->emulateAreaCode('adminhtml', Array, Array)
#30 /var/www/html/stacked-skincare.local/vendor/aheadworks/module-freeshippinglabel/Setup/InstallData.php(76): Magento\Framework\App\State\Interceptor->emulateAreaCode('adminhtml', Array, Array)
#31 /var/www/html/stacked-skincare.local/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(979): Aheadworks\Freeshippinglabel\Setup\InstallData->install(Object(Magento\Setup\Module\DataSetup), Object(Magento\Setup\Model\ModuleContext))
#32 /var/www/html/stacked-skincare.local/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(874): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->handleDBSchemaData(Object(Magento\Setup\Module\DataSetup), 'data', Array)
#33 [internal function]: Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->installDataFixtures(Array)
#34 /var/www/html/stacked-skincare.local/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(367): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#35 /var/www/html/stacked-skincare.local/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Controller/Install.php(109): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->install(Array)
#36 /var/www/html/stacked-skincare.local/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractActionController.php(84): Magento\Setup\Controller\Install->startAction()
#37 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#38 /var/www/html/stacked-skincare.local/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(490): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#39 /var/www/html/stacked-skincare.local/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(260): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#40 /var/www/html/stacked-skincare.local/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractController.php(118): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#41 /var/www/html/stacked-skincare.local/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/DispatchListener.php(118): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response))
#42 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#43 /var/www/html/stacked-skincare.local/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(490): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#44 /var/www/html/stacked-skincare.local/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(260): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#45 /var/www/html/stacked-skincare.local/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Application.php(340): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#46 /var/www/html/stacked-skincare.local/setup/index.php(39): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
#47 {main}
```

**Getting this error when running `setup:upgrade`**

```
/var/www/html/stacked-skincare.local$ php bin/magento s:up
Cache cleared successfully
File system cleanup:
/var/www/html/stacked-skincare.local/generated/code/Amasty
/var/www/html/stacked-skincare.local/generated/code/Composer
/var/www/html/stacked-skincare.local/generated/code/Fastly
/var/www/html/stacked-skincare.local/generated/code/Magento
/var/www/html/stacked-skincare.local/generated/code/Symfony
The directory '/var/www/html/stacked-skincare.local/generated/metadata/' doesn't exist - skipping cleanup
Updating modules:
Invalid entity_type specified: customer
```

Comment: Have you tried disabling the module throwing the error? Aheadworks_Freeshippinglabel is not a default magento module, try installing it later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, i found my solution, the problem was this modules `Aheadworks_Freeshippinglabel` `Aheadworks_Onestepcheckout` `Aheadworks_OrderSuccessPage`.

After cloning from `github`, i removed some chunk form these 2 file:

**From `composer.json` i removed these lines:**

```
    "repositories": {
        "aheadworks": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://dist.aheadworks.com"
        },
     }

    "require": {
        "aheadworks/module-freeshippinglabel": "^1.0",
        "aheadworks/module-onestepcheckout": "^1.3",
        "aheadworks/module-order-success-page": "^1.0",
     }
```

**From `composer.lock` i removed these lines:**

```
    "packages": [
        {
            "name": "aheadworks/module-freeshippinglabel",
            "version": "1.0.3",
            .....
            .......
        },
        {
            "name": "aheadworks/module-onestepcheckout",
            "version": "1.3.3",
            .....
            .......
        },
        {
            "name": "aheadworks/module-order-success-page",
            "version": "1.0.1",
            .....
            .......
    ]
```

After that i run `composer install` for all remaining files and folder. So the composer didn't install these module.

After that install `Magento` and in runs perfectly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have a custom module enabled (`Aheadworks_Freeshippinglabel`) which is throwing an error. Disable the module by unselecting it in the installation process before installing and enabling it later.

Answer (score 1):

> **Disable `Aheadworks_Freeshippinglabel` Module And Try Because Of That Error occur of This Module**

**Follow This Command :-**

```
php bin/magento module:disable Aheadworks_Freeshippinglabel

php bin/magento s:up

php bin/magento c:f

chmod -R 777 pub/ var/ generated/
```

**Also You Can Disable Module Manualy :-**

> **app/etc/config.php**

**From :-**

```
'Aheadworks_Freeshippinglabel' => 1,
```

**To :-**

```
'Aheadworks_Freeshippinglabel' => 0,
```

Comment: Can't run `setup:upgrade` getting error, updated question with error... @RkRathod